# Nautilus crashes after installing 'Nautilus Columns'

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-extensions

I just installed Nautilus Columns (Nautilus extension) in Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and after installing it I can't open Nautilus it just Crashes/Closes when I try opening it.

This is the message I get from the command line when I run Nautilus :

```
Initializing nautilus-ideviceinfo extension
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
import gobject._gobject
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/arista-nautilus.py", line 38, in
import nautilus
ImportError: No module named nautilus
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 0.7.1
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Does anyone have any ideas because I would like to get this working.

Comment: independently of the answer you get here, please file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

After a suggestion from another user named Andrew he suggested I uninstall Arista due to something in the output in the command I posted and the Nautilus and Nautilus-Columns worked fine together. I also reinstalled Arista and didn't get anymore crashes with Nautilus as well

Answer (score 0):

According to the PPA here

[image: nautilus-columns]

It is unclear whether it is compatible with Precise . Please file a bug report by following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: Please post your solution as answer in detail , and accept it as answer. It will help others having same problem.